# How to compare just the date part and not the time of two Dates?

Tags: vb.net, date, compare

I want to compare just the date part (and Not the time) of two VB.NET Date objects.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Just take the date part of each via the `Date` property and compare the two:

```
date1.Date.CompareTo(date2.Date)
```

Or:

```
If date1.Date < date2.Date Then
```

Comment: I'll remove the text about it then. Just for anyone following along, Konrad's comment made sense at the time :)

Comment: Thanks Jared. When I answer VB questions there's almost always a bit of syntactic guesswork involved :)

Answer (score 9):

You could also use TimeSpan

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan
ts = dt1 - dt2
```

ts.Days will now have the difference of the two dates as whole days.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I often use (dt1-dt2).Days as a quick diff.

Answer (score 7):

Compare the DateTime.Date properties.

Answer (score 6):

Change the txt1 date to format dd/mm/yyyy using `myDateTime.ToShortDateString()` so that both the dates will be in same format.
then :

```
if (DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) > 0) 
// which means ("date1 > date2")
if (DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) == 0) 
//which means ("date1 == date2");
if (DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) < 0) 
//which means ("date1 < date2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim backDateCount As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CDate(dtpCheckIn.SelectedDate.Value).Date, Date.Now.Date)
```

> **Date.Now.Date:** #12/4/2018 12:00:00 AM#
>
> **Date.Now:**      #12/4/2018 03:23:34 PM#

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim date1, date2 As Date
date1 = Date.Parse(dtpStart.Text)
date2 = Date.Parse(dtpEnd.Text)
If (DateTime.Compare(date1, date2) > 0) Then ' which means ("date1 > date2") 
    MessageBox.Show("يجب تحديد  الفترة للتاريخ بشكل صحيح  ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading)
    Exit Sub
End If
```