# How to connect database to Report or Report Wizard in Visual Basic 2012?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

My database is Vertrigo(MySql) and i don't know how to connect my database to report or report wizard in Visual Basic 2012. I need the report or report wizard in order to  print all the data that i have in my database. Can you help me? Please?

Comment: If you can use Vertrigo at all, then you can presumably retrieve datasets from it, or at least retrieve data and populate objects. That's all you need in order to use reports. So it's unclear just where your difficulty lies.

Comment: i just don't know how to do it. I tried different tutorials but it's not working

Comment: You will have to show your code, and be a lot more specific than 'it's not working'. You say you have tried different tutorials, so that's a start. [Here's another one which may help](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/magreer/2008/10/16/setting-the-datasource-for-a-report-at-runtime/) You can also do something similar with a list of objects rather than a dataset. Either way, this separates the reporting from the data - presumably you already know how to deal with the data side of things ie pull datasets from Vertrigo.